# Is there a way in the LLVM Compiler Infrastructure to cast a pointer constant to a pointer constant of a different type?

Tags: pointers, casting, llvm, constants

I've got a constant pointer of type `*TypeB` from the address of a global variable and I need to cast it to a pointer of type `*TypeA` where `TypeB` is different from `TypeA` but is also a valid `TypeA`.

For example `TypeA` might have the members `(uint id, int data1)` and `TypeB` might have the members `(uint id, int data1, int data2)`.

The question is how do cast a **constant** pointer to a different type while keeping it **constant** (without instructions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `bitcast` [constant expression](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions), obviously.

See [documentation](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html#ae79d05dd3d0b05e080e08f8c5c33f880) for `ConstantExpr::getBitCast()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But could you remove "obviously"?